# Angular JS if-else not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
    <body ng-app ng-controller="progressCircleController">
<h1 class="errorHeader">List of Classes</h1>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="progressModal" class="container" role="dialog">
    <form>
        <ul class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <li ng-click="showErrorDetails(key)" class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 eachClassCell"
                ng-repeat='(key,value) in sampleJSON'>
                <div ng-if="{{value.length}} <= 50">
                    <div title="{{key}}" class="progress green">{{key}}
                        <span class="progress-left">
                            <span class="progress-bar"></span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="progress-right">
                            <span class="progress-bar"></span>
                        </span>
                        <div class="progress-value">{{key}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div ng-if="{{value.length}} >= 50">
                    <div title="{{key}}" class="progress red">{{key}}
                        <span class="progress-left">
                            <span class="progress-bar"></span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="progress-right">
                            <span class="progress-bar"></span>
                        </span>
                        <div class="progress-value">{{key}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

The progress circle created for each key is duplicate. I need to draw the progress circle based on the value.length of every key such that when value.length > 50 then draw the red circle and the value.length <=50 the draw the green circle.

Comment: There is no `>==` operator in JavaScript. Voting to close as typo. The operator is `>=`.

Comment: Even changing the operator to `>=` draws each progress circle twice.

Comment: Well, obviously you have to debug it. That starts with things like not ignoring the errors shown to you in the web console, as apparently you were with `>==`. While there are some values that are neither `< 50` nor `>= 50`, such as `NaN` or `"frog"`, but I can't immediately think of one that's *both* `< 50` and `>= 50`. It would also help you and others if you indent your HTML consistently and clearly. Perhaps the structure isn't quite what you think, with the indentation all over the place.

Comment: @Nagendra555 have you checked the length ?

Is it possible that you got the length 50 thats why you got that result.

I think the condition should be {{value.length}} <= 50 & {{value.length}} > 50.

just a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It was angular js version issue.
And the div should be `<div ng-if="value.length <= 50">` because it is already inside angular context.

Comment: @Nagendra555: If you flesh out that comment with details of the versions and such, that's worth posting as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was angular js version issue.
I was using old angular js version (1.0.7) which I think does not recognize the `>` or `<` or any logical operator and it does not even throw any error in console.
Used angular JS version 1.2.29 and worked perfectly.

And changed the div to `<div ng-if="value.length <= 50">` because it is already inside angular context.